TypeScript Error: Dynamic route params not recognized properly
I am building a markdown-based blog using Next.js v15's app directory and dynamic routes. However, I am encountering a TypeScript error when trying to handle params in a dynamic route when I try to npm run build.
Here is the error:
next/types/app/blogpost/[slug]/page.ts:34:13
Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<Promise<{ params: { slug: string; }; }>, keyof PageProps, "default">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
  Property 'then' is incompatible with index signature.
Type '<TResult1 = { params: { slug: string; }; }, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: { params: { slug: string; }; }) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | ... 1 more ... | undefined) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type 'never'.

Here is my dynamic route file (app/blogpost/[slug]/page.tsx):
import MaxWidthWrapper from '@/components/MaxWidthWrapper';
import React from 'react';
import { unified } from "unified";
import remarkParse from "remark-parse";
import remarkRehype from "remark-rehype";
import rehypeSlug from 'rehype-slug';
import rehypeStringify from "rehype-stringify";
import matter from "gray-matter";
import fs from "fs";
import rehypeAutolinkHeadings from 'rehype-autolink-headings';
import { rehypePrettyCode } from 'rehype-pretty-code';
import { transformerCopyButton } from '@rehype-pretty/transformers';
import { Metadata } from 'next';

type Props = {
  params: { slug: string };
};

export default async function BlogPage(params: Promise<{ params: { slug: string } }>) {
  const { params: { slug } } = await params;
  const filePath = `content/${slug}.md`;
  const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath, "utf-8");
  const { data, content } = matter(fileContent);

  const processor = unified()
    .use(remarkParse)
    .use(remarkRehype)
    .use(rehypeSlug)
    .use(rehypePrettyCode, {
      theme: "github-dark",
      transformers: [
        transformerCopyButton({
          visibility: 'always',
          feedbackDuration: 3000,
        }),
      ],
    })
    .use(rehypeAutolinkHeadings)
    .use(rehypeStringify);

  const htmlContent = (await processor.process(content)).toString();

  return (
    <MaxWidthWrapper className="prose dark:prose-invert">
      <div className="px-16">
        <h1>{data.title}</h1>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlContent }}></div>
      </div>
    </MaxWidthWrapper>
  );
}

export async function generateMetadata({ params }: Props): Promise<Metadata> {
  const filePath = `content/${params.slug}.md`;
  const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath, "utf-8");
  const { data } = matter(fileContent);

  return {
    title: data.title,
    description: data.description,
    openGraph: {
      images: [
        {
          url: data.imgUrl,
        },
      ],
    },
  };
}

When I navigate to a route like /blogpost/my-post, the app fails to compile due to the above type error.
Do you have a solution. I am not very experimented with typescript.
